# SparkSQL set the type of inputSchema of UDAF fits all data types

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I tried to wrote a UDAF function to calculate the null rate of a column (how many percentage of items in a column is NULL). So theoretically, we do not need to care about the type of the column (no matter it is DoubleType or IntegerType or others), so long as it is NULL or NOT NULL.

So I wrote the code as follows:

```
class nullDoubleRate extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
    override def inputSchema : StructType = StructType(Array(StructField("value", DoubleType, true)))
    override def bufferSchema : StructType = StructType(Array(
        StructField("count", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("total", IntegerType, true)
    ))
    override def dataType : DataType = DoubleType
    override def deterministic : Boolean = true
    override def initialize(buffer : MutableAggregationBuffer) : Unit = {
        buffer(0) = 0
        buffer(1) = 0
    }
    override def update(buffer : MutableAggregationBuffer, input : Row) : Unit = {
        if (input.isNullAt(0)) {
            buffer(0) = buffer.getInt(0) + 1
        }
        buffer(1) = buffer.getInt(1) + 1
    }
    override def merge(buffer1 : MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2 : Row) : Unit = {
        buffer1(0) = buffer1.getInt(0) + buffer2.getInt(0)
        buffer1(1) = buffer1.getInt(1) + buffer2.getInt(1)
    }
    override def evaluate(buffer : Row) : Double = {
        1.0 * buffer.getInt(0) / buffer.getInt(1)
    }
}
```

My problem is, my code limit the input type as DataType (the second line), while I want extends it to any type (Since calculate the NULL rate do not care about the what type it really are).

I have tried to set DoubleType -> DataType, but DataType seems not a right way since DataType is an abstract class.